# How would I use "Inner join" and "if not exists" in this case?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have 2 main tables: `drivers` and `driver_riders` that are connected by a foreign key. Every day some of the drivers make a single or multiple rides.

And I also have a table `driver_rewards`:

```
driver_rewards
---
  ride_id
  reward_percent
  reward_amount
```

How would I scan `rides`, select `status = success` rides and insert a reward record into `driver_rewards` but  **only** for those rides that haven't been inserted yet -- there's been no record with `ride_id = ?` in `driver_rewards` so far, that is.

How to properly write a SQL query that would select such `rides`? I'm aware of `LEFT JOIN` and `NOT EXISTS` but how would I use them here?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure on the columns in the other tables, but it'll look something like this:

```
INSERT INTO driver_rewards

SELECT ride_id, NULL, NULL
FROM rides r
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM driver_rewards rew WHERE rew.ride_id = r.ride_id)
   AND r.status = 'success'
```